# Inserting Blankspaces in Lawson Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

We have a Lawson Oracle Database Table called GLTRASREL, where we need  to insert  the values from the CSV file and this is taken care by the BizTalk Application. Certain fields in the Table is like

`JRNL-BOOK-NBR      Alpha 12                                  GL165   GL65.1
Element: Journal Book NThe journal book assigned to the          IFLR.1
                       transaction.`

So when I try pass nothing into this field it says `"ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("DEVLAW"."GLTRANSREL"."JRNL_BOOK_NBR")"`

In mapping I tried to pass the 12 blank spaces using the Scripting Functoid like

```
 public string GetJournalBookNo()
 {
   return "            ";
 }
```

It again throws the same error. If I give 10 blankspaces with Single quotes (12chars total)like

```
    return '          ';
```

It inserts but like shown below

[image]

How should I be inserting blank spaces in to this field.

Tried enabling tracking to see what is being passed in to the Oracle DB, I see the blank spaces in the field but still throws error like. `ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("DEVLAW"."GLTRANSREL"."JRNL_BOOK_NBR")`

[image]

Comment: Are you using the WCF Oracle Adapter or the Lawson LOB Adapter?

Comment: I am using WCF-Custom Adapter here

Comment: With Message Tracking enabled, can you check the message that hit's the Adapter?  Do you see the blanks?

Comment: @Johns-305 I tried tracking enabled when I see the tracked messgaes i can see the blank spaces like I edited in the question

Comment: And I presume if you put some actual character in there it works...this is unexpected.  I've not experienced the adapter doing anything like a trim on it's own.

Comment: Yes if we any characters it is working like we tried putting '     ' blanks spaces enclosed in single quotes. It inserts them.

Comment: So, this is super weird.  Can you try a non-breaking space?  char 160?  Be aware, that might break downstream components.

Comment: how would I be passing the non-breaking space in the maps. I am sorry I am not getting you.

Comment: you can try something like return "     ".Replace(" ", "\u00A0");  The non-breaking space is a space character with a different value.